# Is it possible to create a notification trigger for any change or update to all stored procedures in a Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to create a notification trigger for any change or update to all stored procedures in a database?

Comment: This post shows no effort or research on your part. What have you spent time researching, implementing, and found to not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Sure, I wrote about [exactly this, here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use a trigger to send an email alert

Update below

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;

GO
CREATE TRIGGER reminder2
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_PROCEDURE, ALTER_PROCEDURE, DROP_PROCEDURE
AS
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'AdventureWorks2008R2 Administrator',
    @recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',
    @body = 'Don''t forget to print a report for the sales force.',
    @subject = 'Reminder';
GO
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This trigger sends an alert when a record in Sales.Customer is inserted, deleted or updated, correct? If I am understanding, OP would like to send  a notification when any stored procedure is modified. Seems to be a different requirement.

Comment: Good catch Jacob, I read through too quickly that OP was looking for a trigger on a stored procedure modification.

Comment: Yes I have created a trigger for a table before but am just wondering if it would be possible to apply that to every single Stored Procedure in ones database?

Comment: Yes Cesta, thank you. I have never seen such a process done so I was wondering if this was at all possible. =)

Comment: it looks to be possible to create one for procedures on CREATE_PROCEDURE, DROP_PROCEDURE or ALTER_PROCEDURE.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-events

Comment: Neither have I @GeorgeJones

Comment: So I was able to successfully create a trigger that sends me an email every time any stored procedure is altered, created or dropped. Now would it be possible for the trigger to name the specific Stored Procedure that was altered and include that in the email?